# Why is my dynamic SQL resulting in the error shown below?

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to build a SQL statement dynamically and this is one variation of the result.

```
sqlQuery {
  name: 'fetch-products',
  text: 'select * from products where category = 
  $1 and designer in $2',
  values: [ 'WOMENSCLOTHING', "('Adjavon', 'ALC', 'Adele', 'Bagley')" ]
}
```

I build the sql with the following code segment:

```
const {
    category,
    designers,
} = JSON.parse(filters);

let values = [category];

let text = 'select * from products where category = $1';

if(designers) {
    text = text + ' and designer in $2';
    values.push(designers);
}
```

I execute it in the following segment:

```
try {
    const allProducts = await pool.query(sqlQuery);

    res.status(200).json(allProducts.rows);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).send('Problems getting products by category.')
}
```

And get the following error:

> Error: syntax error at or near "$2"

I am thinking the error may be the double quotes placed around designer when it is pushed on the values array:

```
values: [ 'WOMENSCLOTHING', "('Adjavon', 'ALC', 'Adele', 'Bagley')" ]
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look at [pg-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise). It is built on top of node-postgres but adds a few very nice features. Search the docs page for "CSV filter" (or [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise#csv-filter)) and you'll find an example that uses something in the form of `WHERE x IN ($1:csv)` and then supports taking an array as input for $1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what library you are using exactly, but the `values` property looks highly suspicious.

```
sqlQuery {
  name: 'fetch-products',
  text: 'select * from products where category = 
  $1 and designer in $2',
  values: [ 'WOMENSCLOTHING', "('Adjavon', 'ALC', 'Adele', 'Bagley')" ]
}
```

If your drivr/library supports this, the second element in the array should be an actual array and not a string like `'("foo", "bat")'`. How is the driver supposed to know this is meant as a list and not a single string that has this value?

I guess in a nutshell you have to bring the query in this form:

```js
const query = 'select * from products where category = $1 and designer in ($2, $3, $4, $5)'

const values =  [ 'WOMENSCLOTHING', 'Adjavon', 'ALC', 'Adele', 'Bagley' ]
```

That requires some extra work on the backend to map the values and bring them into the right shape.

I guess you could get that done with something like this:

```js
const category = 'icecream'
const designers = ['jim', 'maria']

let values = [category];

let text = 'select * from products where category = $1';

if (designers) {
  text += ` and designer in (${designers.map((d, i) => `$${i+2}`).join(', ')})`;
  values = [...values, ...designers];
}

console.log(text);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: I modeled my sql statement after an example on node-postgress.com. It can be found here under Prepared Statement. https://node-postgres.com/features/queries

Comment: @koque, I don't find a `IN Clause` on this docs page. I really think you need to put the individual values of your in clause as paramaters.